# Support for a 6000 lb spa, measuring 9'x 7.5', filled with water

Tags: wood

16' x 16' treated wood deck with of 2 x 6 treated decking, supported by nine 6" x 6" vertical treated wood posts with 2 x 10 floor joist, 16" on center.

Will that deck support a spa weighing 6000 lbs?

Comment: Are there additional support members under the 2x10 joists that in turn rest on the nine vertical posts?

Comment: Another two questions. How high are the 6x6 posts? And are the 2x10 joists doing the full 16' span or are they center supported to provide two 8' spans?

Comment: The 6 x 6 post stand about 6'6" above ground.  There are 2 x 12's bolted through the post on the outside perimeter, then the 2 x 10's run the length of the deck (about 16') with 2 joist sandwiched on both sides of the center line of poles (6" apart) and every 4' feet there are 2 x 10's sandwiched between the 16'' on center 2 x 10's which prevent them from moving in either direction.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully follow your description of the framing. If there are no triangulation braces from the lower part of the posts up to the upper framing I would be leery of placing a 3 or more ton load on top of the deck even if the joist structure itself could take the static load.

Comment: There are no triangular braces on or under the deck.  The post are bolted and nailed through the 2x12s forming the outside of the deck. The 2x16s run paralled from the south end to the north end.

Comment: The deck currently has a 325-350 gallon spa on it measuring 6.5x6.5'.  Want to upgrade to larger 9.0 x 7.5' spa which is deeper and holds 550 gallons of water.

Comment: The 2x16s are supported by the 2x12s at each end and have support braces between them to prevent them from bowing or twisting for the length of the 16'

Comment: Now it's 2x16 joists? Sounds like there is enough unsureness here that you should definitely get a structural engineer out to run some calculations and make appropriate recommendations.

Comment: From what I've gleaned so far I would say that the answer to your question is probably no based upon looking at an online beam load calculator.

Comment: Sorry the joists are 2x10's, 16 feet long.